# what languages are supported in realbasic?

Tags: php, macos, realbasic, realstudio

a friend told me that i possibly can create mac applications via the php plugin in realbasic. is this true? ive searched the net like crazy and the syntax doesnt
look anything close to php using the plugin that is. all u do is write function calls and write your php in it. but that is kind of dumb. what i wanna know is what languages are supported in this app and what lanuage is it or close to that i see in its tutorials? thnx

Answer (score 4):

REAL Studio (formerly called REALbasic) is a fully object oriented BASIC language that compiles native Macintosh OS X, Windows and Linux executables.  The IDE contains all of the editors and compilers needed to create applications.

[Monkeybread Software](http://www.monkeybreadsoftware.de/realbasic/plugins.shtml) offers a php plugin that allows you to *call* php scripts in REALbasic.  They also offer a way to use Java classes from within a REALbasic application.  Plugins, in general, allow you to call C code outside of the RB frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Can REALBasic do this?

A [Review of REALBasic](http://www.developer.com/lang/other/article.php/2214191/A-Review-of-REALBasic.htm) says

> REALBasic is tool that allows programmers to develop applications using the BASIC programming language ... REALBasic will also create applications for MAC OS Classic and MAC OS X.

Your friend may have been mistaken about support for other languages.

Comment: but what language does
it use?

Comment: ... Wouldn't that be BASIC? Rather, REALbasic.

Comment: sorry if this sounds dumb but is its language the only one? the reason i ask is because i saw a php plugin and was wondering on its purpose

Comment: It uses REALbasic, a dialect of basic. There are ways to support plugins, I believe in C, and like someone mentioned there are plugins that allow you to extend capabilities. Go to the REAL Software website and email their people if you want more information; their support people are generally really good with answering questions fairly quickly.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a late clarification, but probably needs to be done since there's a bit of confusion here.

Short answer: YES. You can use PHP in REALStudio (the IDE to REALBasic). Most of the answers above err on the too strict or too lax interpretations for some reason.

REALBasic is the language.
REALStudio is the IDE and compiler.

REALStudio accepts plug-ins that can be called from within the IDE using REALBasic. These plug-ins can do anything programmatically possible, including calling other language interpreters.

There are plug-is for PHP, Lua, JavaScript and other languages. These, when the plug-in is included, offer functions that can be called to execute scripts and deal with the result. It doesn't mean that these language's functions are added to REALStudio's, but that the whole interpreter can be run, in the same way you'd run it in the command line.

```
'Comments in REALBasic start with a '
'Double quotes are escaped by doubling them, ""like so""

'Initialize a new PHP object
dim p as PHPMBS
p=new PHPMBS

'Put the PHP code into a string
dim phpFunction as string = "echo ""Hello"";"

'Result is a string variable where the result will be assigned
dim result as string

'Assign the result of the PHP Function to the string variable
result=p.Execute(phpFunction)

'Pop up an alert with the message
msgBox result
```

Of course, you can include whole PHP files into your executable and call them and execute them, the result can be text or an image you can do stuff with afterwards or feed into yet another PHP function.

Imagine the PHP engine compiled as a library and accessible to your executable, like in most other languages/IDEs.

Keep in mind the PHP plug-in is currently a 3rd party module that needs to be paid for.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your friend was thinking of Yuma?  It allows you to do web site site scripting (much like PHP) using REALbasic.

http://www.yumadev.com/

Answer (score 0):

REALStudio is an IDE for REAL Software's version of BASIC. It compiles for MacOS, Windows and Linux. The IDE supports one language- BASIC.